# Getting double velocity vectors to calculate correctly without rounding

Tags: java, eclipse, double, collision-detection, trigonometry

I'm currently writing a simple game where there are a number of towns with a certain number of soldiers that increments every second. Towns owned by one player can attack a town owned by another player, causing the amount of soldiers in the original town to split in half, with the other half going to attack the other town.

The issue is that I represent the attacking soldiers as a shape heading towards the other town, and I use collision detection to figure out when the `Attack` arrives. Therefore, it's important that the vector the `Attack` uses to reach the town is correct so that it actually reaches the town.

Every town has a `Point` field called an `attackPoint` which I use as the origin  point for attacks as well as the destination for them to head to. The `attackPoint` is located in the middle of the collision field.

Here's the code I have which initializes an `Attack` and creates the movement vector:

```
public Attack(int troops, Team owner, Town source, Town destination) {
    this.troops = troops;             //troops included in the attack
    this.owner = owner;               //player that who sent the attack
    this.destination = destination;   //town the attack is going towards

    Point srcPoint = source.getAttackPoint(); //attackPoint of the source
    Point destPoint = destination.getAttackPoint(); //attackPoint of the destination town

    x = srcPoint.x;           //int --- the attack originates at the src's attack point
    y = srcPoint.y;           //int

    double hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(destPoint.y - y, 2) + Math.pow(destPoint.x - x, 2));
    double adjacent = destPoint.x - x;
    double opposite = destPoint.y - y;
    xVelocity = 3.0 * (adjacent / hypotenuse);     //field, double
    yVelocity = 3.0 * (opposite / hypotenuse);
}
```

Then another method actually moves the `Attack` -

```
public void move() {
   x += xVelocity;
   y += yVelocity;
}
```

I can confirm from testing that the `attackPoints` returned by `getAttackPoint()` are both correct, and that the way I do collision detection works fine. The problem here is that it seems either my velocity variables, or some other variables, are getting rounded so that there are only a few predefined paths the `Attack`s can take. For example:

```
//trying to attack X2     //trying to attack X1
X...............                     X------------------
.\..............                     .........X1.....
..\.............                     ................
...\............                     ................
....\...........                     ................
.....X1..X2.....                     ................
```

The "predefined" paths seem to be every 30 degrees or so, and I can send `Attack`s straight up, down, left, and right, which is why I think some rounding error is going on when I'm calculating the vectors and doing the trig.
When I have two towns that are close together, no matter which one I try to attack, both `Attack`s follow the same path (diagram 1). 
Also, when I have a town that is close to 180 degrees east/west of the source town, the `Attack` I send will go directly east/west (diagram 2).

If anyone can see something going wrong or give me a suggestion on how to allow the objects to travel on a direct path from one point or another, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after researching this more and trying a couple different solutions, I'm pretty convinced that there's some rounding error going on - maybe converting the `int` fields of the `Point`s to `double`s, but I'm not sure.

What I did to get it to work is to move all the calculation to the `move()` method so that the line gets recalculated every tick. This is less good for optimization, but I don't have a lot of objects and this helps the `Attack`s move on a dynamic line towards the other towns. I haven't been able to figure out what was causing the issue initially, but making sure that the calculation was able to check itself by recalculating has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although I did check your method of calculating the acceleration of the two dimensions, it seems rather odd.

You need the slope of a line defined by two points (source and destination).

```
double slope = (destination.y - source.y)/(destination.x - source.x);
xVelocity = 1; // do the normalisation as you wish
yVelocity = xVelocity * slope;
```

In general, I suggest you working with vectors instead of x and y variables. You can generalise most operations and make your code much more readable and repetition free (in this case the segment connecting source and destination would be a vector given by destination - source).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this seems to be about what I was doing, albeit a bit simpler. What do you mean by normalization?

Comment: @wizardarrac The slope only defines the direction of the velocity vector. You apply normalization to set the length of the vector, which means speed in this context. Didn't the new formula help?

Comment: It seems like I'm still getting the same problem with the new formula. However, messing around with yours helped me realize something. Whatever number I used to modify the velocity, like the 1 in your example or the 3 in my code, there seems to be that many angles allowable between every 90 degrees. When I set the velocity modifier to something really high, like 30, then the attacks go exactly where they should. The problem is that I can't seem to get that effect with a lower speed.

Comment: @wizardarrac My guess is that the problem is caused by improper rounding somewhere in your code.